# $f(f(x))$ is the number of the number of all positive factors of $x$

Tags: functions

$f:\mathbb Z_+ \to \mathbb Z_+$, and $f(f(x))$ is the number of the number of all positive factors of $x$.

Prove that $f(x)$ is a prime number when $x$ is a prime number.

I have been thinking this problem for a whole month and I still don't have any ideas...

Can someone help me?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x$ is prime if and only if $f(f(x)) = 2$, since this means $x$ has precisely $2$ positive factors.

Thus, we are tasked with showing that whenever $f(f(x)) = 2$ [i.e., x is prime], furthermore $f(f(f(x))) = 2$ [i.e., $f(x)$ is prime].

This amounts to showing that $f(2) = 2$.

Since $2$ has $2$ many positive factors, we have that $f(f(2)) = 2$. Applying $f$ to both sides, we see that $f(f(f(2)) = f(2)$.

Thus, $f(2)$ has $f(2)$ many positive factors; that is, every single positive number $\leq f(2)$ also divides $f(2)$. This can only happen if $f(2) = 1$ or $f(2) = 2$ [for any other positive $n$, we would have that $n - 1$ is a positive value which does not divide $n$].

All that remains is to rule out the possibility that $f(2) = 1$. Note that $f^2(f^2(f(4))) = f^5(4) = f^3(f^2(4)) = f^3(3) = f(f^2(3)) = f(2)$. If $f(2)$ were $1$, we could conclude that $f^2(f^2(f(4))) = 1$. But $f^2(x) = 1$ only when $x$ has precisely $1$ positive factor; i.e., when $x$ is itself $1$. So if $f^2(f^2(f(4))) = 1$, then $f(4)$ itself would be $1$. But we would also have that $f(1) = f(f(2)) = 2$, so that $f(f(4)) = f(1) = 2$, in contradiction to the appropriate $f(f(4)) = 3$. Having reached a contradiction, we can conclude that $f(2) \neq 1$, completing the proof.

Comment: Thanks for the solution!